# Utility to TRIM unallocated space on drive

Tags: partition, sd-card, trim

I have a drive (SD card) with a few ext4 partitions but also some unallocated space. The `fstrim` utility can only work within a filesystem. Before I reinvent the wheel and write one, is there another utility that can TRIM the unallocated space (or that can TRIM an explicitly specified range)?

I can verify that the majority of the unallocated space on the device is *not* currently known to be free by the controller, as I've observed that, on this particular card, reads to trimmed space return 0's, but a scan of the device shows plenty of garbage data left over.

Edit: I am having an issue using `hdparm`. The example below discards the first sector, but I am seeing the same results regardless of the range I specify. `fstrim` has no issues on the device:

```
root@ubuntu:~# hdparm --please-destroy-my-drive --trim-sector-ranges 0:1 --verbose /dev/mmcblk0 

/dev/mmcblk0:
trimming 1 sectors from 1 ranges
outgoing cdb:  85 0d 06 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 06 00
outgoing_data:  
00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

ioctl(fd,SG_IO): Invalid argument
FAILED: Invalid argument
```

I am investigating further but does anybody have any insight?

Comment: If you map the unpartitioned space with one or more partition(s) (temporarily), you could use `blkdiscard` on them which trims the entire device.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like the right tool, but `blkdiscard` does not seem to be available in my standard package repositories (Ubuntu 12.04, doesn't seem to be present in `util-linux`).

Comment: I was never able to get `hdparm` working for me for some reason, but I grabbed the util-linux source from https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/tree/stable/v2.23, built it (`./autogen.sh ; ./configure ; make blkdiscard`) and it's working great. Still mystified about `hdparm` but `blkdiscard` does exactly what I want. Bonus: There's no need to make a temporary filesystem first, you can use `sfdisk -l` to figure out the space between partitions and have `blkdiscard` trim it.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't even aware of `blkdiscard` being able to work with offset/length options. So the temporary partitions I suggested aren't even necessary. Nice!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have a recent enough version of `util-linux`, it contains the tool `blkdiscard` which is able to TRIM entire devices, or ranges within a device using `--offset` and `--length` options.

**Please note:** `blkdiscard` is dangerous, if you let it TRIM the wrong regions, your data is gone!

So you can figure out the unpartitioned (free) regions of your partition table and then TRIM them using this tool. For `msdos` and `gpt` partitions, `parted` provides the free regions like so:

```
# parted -m /dev/sda unit b print free | grep ':free;'
1:17408B:1048575B:1031168B:free;
1:64022904832B:64023240191B:335360B:free;
```

Add a loop to it...

```
while IFS=: read -ra FREE
do
    echo blkdiscard --offset ${FREE[1]%%B} --length ${FREE[3]%%B} /dev/sda
done < <(parted -m /dev/sda unit b print free | grep ':free;')
```

which prints

```
blkdiscard --offset 17408 --length 1031168 /dev/sda
blkdiscard --offset 64022904832 --length 335360 /dev/sda
```

Verify that this output is correct for you, add additional options if you like (verbose?), and finally remove the `echo` so it will be actually executed, and you should be set.

The second command of that example actually fails because the length is too small - it may be worth checking inside the loop, ignore regions smaller than 1MB as they're unlikely to be successfully trimmed.

---

If you are using LVM instead of partitions, you can create a LV for the unoccupied space and trim that:

```
lvcreate -l100%FREE -n blkdiscard SSD-VG
blkdiscard -v /dev/SSD-VG/blkdiscard
lvremove SSD-VG/blkdiscard
```

If you set `issue_discards = 1` in your `lvm.conf`, you can skip the `blkdiscard` call as LVM will issue the TRIM on `lvremove` by itself.

Comment: Thanks! I have remarked this as the answer because it's working for me, even though Michael's answer is also valid. Also I will add what I said in the question comments: If you *don't* have `blkdiscard` available; you can grab util-linux source from https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/tree/stable/v2.23 then build `blkdiscard` (run `./autogen.sh ; ./configure ; make blkdiscard`) -- it built cleanly (although you may have to install some dependencies and tweak `configure` options) and as long as you don't install it, it does not conflict with existing util-linux.

Comment: I was observing failures with certain values passed to `blkdiscard` as well, but noticed the values were based on the offset, not the length. It's possible there is an issue in `blkdiscard`, I am in the process of investigating. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98473/where-is-ioctl-0x1268-blksszget-actually-specified

Comment: I have created a script that does discard free space on all mounted file systems as well as free LVM VGs: https://github.com/stefanct/discard-everything

Comment: Thanks! I never knew that parted can just print the free ranges.

Comment: Can't you just point `blkdiscard` to a partition, i.e. `blkdiscard /dev/sdaX`?

Comment: @RJVB if you're willing to make an (aligned) partition for each unallocated segment, yeah sure! But it could also involve undesired side effects; when you make a partition it's also scanned for UUID, etc. so old contents could pop up when you do so. Also sometimes, changes to partition table don't take until reboot.

Comment: I don't understand, why would you need a single partition per segment? If blkdiscard can determine the block range from the "root" device it should be able to do so also for a "partition" device?

Comment: I did some tests and can confirm that my copy of blkdiscard does indeed work on partitions. You lose some sectors that hold the partition data, though: https://zfsonlinux.topicbox.com/groups/zfs-discuss/T5f3fe69551e04769-Mb36cce6c1b6897755452569a/overprovision-nvme .

Comment: What concerns me more in terms of safety is that I could execute the command without sudo (being a member of the `disk` group, probably).

Comment: @RJVB free space is not necessarily consecutive so if there is more than one free space segment, you need a partition for each. for blkdiscard you need write permission which normal users normally don't have. if you're in the disk group, you can circumvent filesystem permissions which kind of, makes you root already.

Comment: Ah, duh. I was thinking of unallocated space which I left at the end instead of putting another partition on it... And most utilities (like hdparm) still tell me to become root no matter I'm in the disk group ;)

Answer (score 7):

`hdparm --trim-sector-ranges` can trim a range. The man page warns to use it, so you better be sure you got the right range and syntax.

I think sending a trim for all data outside a partition would be dangerous, as there is some hidden data there sometimes like bootloader code or second partition tables. You'd need to know exaclty, which areas outside of partitions are really unused.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I can grab the device size with `hdparm`, unused ranges from `sfdisk`, and trim accordingly. I know what's on the drive. If there is a partioning scheme that hides data in accessible but unallocated areas, that would break any partition editor's basic functionality. I presume (hope) that any schemes like this have long been abandoned (I know of none off the top of my head though). All schemes I know of store the MBR in well-known unallocated space at the start of the device, and VBRs/EBRs within allocated partitions. There may be old obscure schemes that are different. :)

Comment: I am having some difficulty with `hdparm`, I edited my question with details; wondering if you have any insight.

Comment: Seems like at least some of hdparm doesn't work on /dev/mmcblk0. Sorry, I have no further idea.

Answer (score -1):

Note about `blkdiscard` - it is VERY VERY dangerous and can be messy.

I got accident on test system when issuing command:

```
root@test:/home/test# fdisk -l /dev/nvme1n1
Device               Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1        2048    1101823    1099776   537M EFI System
/dev/nvme1n1p2     1134592    1658879     524288   256M Linux RAID
/dev/nvme1n1p3     1658880 1025658879 1024000000 488.3G Linux RAID    
root@test:/home/test# 
root@test:/home/test# blkdiscard /dev/nvme0n1
root@test:/home/test# fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
bash: /usr/sbin/fdisk: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
root@test:/home/test# 
root@test:/home/test# fdisk -l /dev/nvme1n1
bash: /usr/sbin/fdisk: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
root@test:/home/test# fdisk -l /dev/nvme1n1p1 
bash: /usr/sbin/fdisk: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
root@test:/home/test# 
root@test:/home/test# fdisk 
bash: /usr/sbin/fdisk: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

It did TRIM another drive!!!
OS was installed on *nvme1n1p1..3* and *nvme0n1* was test drive.

Fortunately I had complete loss of test system, not big deal, but I feel obligation to share this publicly to warn you.

I think better approach is `fstrim` and set `issue_discards = 1` in `lvm.conf` as mentioned by *frostschutz*

Edit 2024: Despite someone dislike this, I have 30 years of computer experience starting with ZX Spectrum as my first pc.
I am sure that there can be issues and even bugs at OS level mapper, especially on locked partition map situation, or when computer changed boot priority to other efi partition, when efi is present on both disks and system fstab contains efi defined on another disk. There *can be* multiple scenarios, thus `blkdiscard` command should be used with ***EXTREME CAUTION*** and my big recommendation is fresh system boot (reboot) before using it. This command **destroys data**.

Comment: It is dangerous that's for sure. But your results don't seem like a blkdiscard bug; it doesn't really make sense (and also I've seen its source code). I strongly suspect that either the device names weren't mapped to the devices you thought they were mapped to, or your /usr/sbin wasn't on the device you thought it was on.

Comment: I am sure root fs was not on the device to be trimmed. But OS level name mapping can be an issue. In this case it's even more dangerous, as there is uncertainty which device will be destroyed. I have thoughts that may be this is efi bios related, but it's weird that fdisk and smartctl showed identification in one way, while blkdiscard treated names other way. Will update title not to be pointing to a bug.