# dd command bs option at end of disk

Tags: dd

If I were to use the `dd` command as follows:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=16M
```

What happens at the end of the disk if it is not an exact multiple of 16M?  Does that mean the last remaining portion of the disk is not zeroed?

I noticed in https://www.marksanborn.net/howto/wiping-a-hard-drive-with-dd/, he writes that the US Government uses

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda bs=8b conv=notrunc
```

Is the `conv=notrunc` option the way to ensure every last byte is wiped?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The whole output device is wiped whether its size is a multiple of the block size you pass to `dd` or not.

The `notrunc` flag has no effect when the output is a device file, because truncating a device file has no effect. If the output was a regular file, it would have the effect that the output file is not truncated before writing, which on some filesystems means that the old data is overwritten (as opposed to writing new blocks of data and leaving the rest unattached), however this wouldn't be useful since this property is not guaranteed by all filesystems and furthermore the command would not only overwrite the file, but also keep writing until it's filled the output disk (or some other error occurs).

Instead of using `dd` and worrying about whether you're using it correctly (as it happens, it works in this particular case, but [it's complicated](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial) and [sometimes doesn't work](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32988/why-does-dd-from-dev-random-give-different-file-sizes)), [just use `cat`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days).

```
cat /dev/zero >/dev/sdX
```

Despite popular belief on the web, there is absolutely no magic in `dd` that makes it somehow better suited to writing to a disk. The magic is in the `/dev` files. Any tool that can cope with binary data, such as any modern `cat` or `head`, can do the same job as `dd` unless you're passing flags such as `seek` or `skip`.

Note that a problem shared by `dd` and `cat` is that on successful operation, they'll error out with “No space left on device” (ENOSPC). If you put this in a script, you'll either need to check that the error is ENOSPC or use a different method. A more reliable method is to first determine the size of the device (e.g. using `/proc/partitions` under Linux), then write exactly the right number of bytes with a tool such as `head`.

```
size=$(</proc/partitions awk '$4 == "sdX" {print $3}')
head -c "${size}k" /dev/zero >/dev/sdX
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no problem — `dd` writes to the very end (`No space left on device`), unless it runs out of input, is limited by `count=x`, or another error occurs (e.g. bad sectors, lousy cable etc.).

If overwriting an entire blockdevice is your goal, `shred` is easier to use.

```
shred -v -n 1 /dev/deleteme     # pseudorandom data
shred -v -n 0 -z /dev/deleteme  # zeroes
```

Or [`cryptsetup`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352378/30851) for random data with a verification step (zeroes are encrypted to random data; random data is decrypted back to zeroes).

Or [`blkdiscard`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98304/30851) for SSDs.

Or [`wipefs`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394999/30851) if it's just about starting over from scratch, not forcibly getting rid of everything you ever stored on a drive.