# Truncate unallocated space from SD card

Tags: armbian

I have an Armbian system SD card that I want to copy to another device. The system was 16GB but was previously imaged to 64GB card and now it is to big to handle for me. Is it any way to truncate unallocated space from the SD card?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Utility to TRIM unallocated space on drive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97143/utility-to-trim-unallocated-space-on-drive)

Comment: Though honestly, why not just take an image of the first 14.4 GB and be done with it?

Comment: (you might want to run `fstrim` on the ext4 file system first, but that's about it.)

Comment: It fails with "the discard operation is not supported"

Comment: Then the SD card literally doesn't support truncation, and you'll have to overwrite with zeros, just to get an image containing zeros. So, really, just do an image of the first 14.4 GB of your SD card and be done. It makes no difference!

Comment: I think the OP was never thinking about "sparsing". Apparently he really just mean "(re-)shortening", which can easily done with `dd` or even `head`. (Use `fdisk -l` to find out where the last/only partition ends.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller FWIW, most SD cards do have discard/TRIM-like [command(s)](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.5/source/drivers/mmc/core/block.c#L1106), and they often result in "read zero". It's just most if not all *USB* reader does not implement any command translation (from e.g. SCSI UNMAP) in their bridge chip.

Comment: @TomYan true! I remember that being a more common problem when USB FullSpeed readers were still the main thing in the low-cost market! Had totally forgotten about that layer of translation!